# How i can get only what i s inside a double quote with a regexp?

Tags: regex, shell

How can i get the url without the double quotes from this string:

```
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://xxx/aaa/index.html">here</a>.</p>
```

Comment: awk 'NR==6{print;exit}' a.html | grep [\"].*[\"] . i used awk just to pick up the line i want

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex pattern `http:[^"]+`

Comment: i used grep /http:[^"]+/ and i got the prompt. This doesn't work . Can you explain a bit?

Comment: @curious - Learn how to use grep: `grep --h`

Comment: thanx i didn't know --h was the solution. Your comment was really useful

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the html string is in a file called "regexp.html"

```
$ ruby -n -e 'm = $_.match(/(http[^"]+)/); puts m if m' < regexp.html 
http://xxx/aaa/index.html
```

This will only work if the url starts with "http".